# Model properties custom names with url-formencoded

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having an issue with binding in webapi (.net core 2.1).
Usually when I use xml/json, I can add attributes to the model props (either via XmlElement or JsonProperty).
I have a project however that uses application/x-www-form-urlencoded as media type and thus, the models only work if the names of the params match the property names (luckily case insensitive). Can you advise if there is a way to implement such mapping?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can annotate your model properties with the [`FromForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) attribute, which has a property [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute.name?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_FromFormAttribute_Name) that specifies the name to use when binding. Here's an example:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    [FromForm(Name = "SomePropertyNameToUse")]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "SomeOtherPropertyNameToUse")]
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```